# Total Variation in Probability Intuition

Tags: probability, statistics, intuition

Let $\Omega$ be a finite probability space and define the Total Variation as $TV(\mu,\nu):=\sup\{|\mu(A)-\nu(A)|: A\subseteq\Omega\}$. One can also derive that

$TV(\mu,\nu)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{x\in\Omega}|\mu(x)-\nu(x)|$

I know how to derive this fact by showing $\leq$ and $\geq$, however, I am interested if there is a direct way of deriving this. My hope is that such a direct proof would hint at the intuition behind maximizing over the largest event, compared to looking at the total sum of differences.

Comment: Did you get something out of the answer below? If this is so, you might *accept* it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The supremum is reached at $A=\{x\in\Omega\,;\,\mu(x)\ge\nu(x)\}$.

Comment: Or it's complement. I see, thanks!

Comment: @Sam At both, and at a few others like $A'=\{x\in\Omega\,;\,\mu(x)>\nu(x)\}$, really.